# Visual clues to copy link to specific answer i.e. include anchor in link

Tags: feature-request

currently it seems like if you want to create a link to a specific answer you have to look in to the source to get the name of the anchor for that answer

Answer (score 2):

There is a "share" link at the bottom of *every* post (question or answer).

Click it and you shall have your link.

> [image: share link]

Comment: Unfortunately this will copy a shorter version of the link so I find my self not using it, consider: `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238434/visual-clues-to-copy-link-to-specific-answer-i-e-include-anchor-in-link#238435` vs. `http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238435/196297` the first version gives much more clues to what is linked to